# why isn‘’t my original variable changed when I pass by reference a formal parameter?

Tags: c++

I have a function that remove the const attribute of the `int*` and change the value of the variable it point to, but it doesn't work since I pass a variable and reference it in the formal reference?

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char UINT8;

int ll(const int &r)
{
  *(const_cast<int *>(&r)) = 5;
  // cout<<const_cast<int*> (&r)<<endl;
  //*(&r)=5;

  cout << r << endl;
}

int main()
{
  const int a = 1;

  ll(a);

  cout << a << endl;
}
```

I expected the value shown in the function to be the same as the one in `main()`, but it's different.

Comment: Attempting to modify a constant variable leads to *undefined behavior*. End of story.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well as [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Also please don't create your own local type-aliases, use [the standard fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) instead, like `std::uint8_t`.

Comment: Compilers trust you completely. When you wrote `const int a = 1;` you said to the compiler, "the value of `a` will never change", but that was a lie. When you lie to the compiler, strange things can happen.

Comment: you mean the compiler doesn't allow me to modify the value of const variable? but why *(const_cast<int *>(&r)) = 5 is allowed in the function body since r is an reference of a? I thought compiler will report errors but I passed unexpectedly and the value is changed successfully to be 5

Comment: @molbdnilo  forgot to @ you

Comment: @CaiyiZhou When you promised that `a` would never change, the compiler relied on that promise and replaced all uses of `a` with its unchanging value, 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attempt to modify const-qualified object `a` causes Undefined Behavior. Language allows to alter types and/or qualifiers of references using `reinterpret_cast` and/or`const_cast` but it is always programmer's responsibility to ensure that the object being accessed through a reference really has appropriate type and qualifiers.

Comment: but why *(const_cast<int *>(&r)) = 5 is allowed in the function body since r is an reference of a? I thought compiler will report errors but it passed unexpectedly and the value is changed successfully to be 5

Comment: @CaiyiZhou *Undefined behaviour is undefined.* Anything can happen. As to why the compiler's not complaining: if `a` had been declared as `int` instead of `const int`, the code would be perfectly correct. Casting away a `const` qualifier when accessing an object which is not actually `const` is not a problem. Doing it on an actually `const` object *is* a problem.

Comment: r is const actually cause compiler report errors of  *(&r)=5 which has been commented by me in the function body. I only cast away pointer of r not r itself, I do so for compilers does not report errors of this line *(const_cast<int *>(&r)) = 5

Comment: @CaiyiZhou `*(const_cast<int *>(&r))` yields a reference of `int` which only effects overload resolution, however the object being referenced is still const qualified and should not be changed. Adjusting qualifiers on reference (or pointer) to object does not change qualifiers on the object itself. Language allows to alter types and qualifiers of references using `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` but it is programmers responsibility to ensure that object being accessed through a reference really has stated type and qualifiers.